# sqlalchemy rollback in INSERTS

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, rollback

I have a small question. I'm inserting a long array of data into a DB, but it can happen that some of the new rows throw an IntegrityError exception. That's fine and I can easily recognize them. The problem is, when I rollback to undo this "fake" insertion, all the previous rows are also deleted.

What I want to do then, is to rollback to the immediate previous status and continue with the next Insert.

```
import sqlalchemy as alc

def insert(self, specs):
    #do stuff to transfor specs in data_db

    entry = Check_Point(data_db)
    session.add(entry)

    try:
        session.flush()

    except alc.exc.IntegrityError:
        print 'int Error'
        session.rollback()
```

So, researching a little bit, I found this:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#using-savepoint

```
for record in records:
    try:
        with session.begin_nested():
            session.merge(record)
    except:
        print "Skipped record %s" % record
session.commit()
```

But I cannot really get it to work, if "records" is an array of the objects to be inserted (in my case instances of Check_Point). I get the following error:

> This Session's transaction has been rolled back by a nested rollback() call.  To begin a new transaction, issue Session.rollback() first

I'm close to solve the problem but need some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Does it support `SAVEPOINT` transactions?

Comment: Hi, it is a SQLite3 Database. It supports Savepoint. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html

I can make it work by trying to commited each new row, but speed is incredibly slow (each time, around 3000 rows have to be inserted)

Thanks!

Comment: I did some tests and there seem to be issues regarding SAVEPOINT and SQLite3. I made post on the SQLAlchemy Group and will get back to you when I have that clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `SAVEPOINT` transactions won't work correctly with *SQLAlchemy* and *SQLite3* due to a *PySQLite* bug. See [this SQLAlchemy Google group post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sqlalchemy/XTUf_Pe4cNA/discussion) for Michael Bayer's detailed explanation about the bug and the complexity of working around it in *SQLAlchemy*.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. 

I finally used a Literal SQL with INSERT OR IGNORE, it is not either the best solution but it works for my purposes. And since it looks complicated to work around, I think I'll stick to my solution as long as I don't need details on the insertion error.

Thanks amigo.